# Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const float **' with an lvalue of type 'float **

Tags: c++

I understand why I can't cast a const to non const, but this is the inverse:

```
    float** inputChannelData = buffer.getArrayOfWritePointers();
    simpleRecorder->processInput(inputChannelData, buffer.getNumChannels(), buffer.getNumSamples());
```

signature:

```
void SimpleRecorder::processInput(const float * *inputChannelData, int numInputChannels, int numSamples)
```

Error:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const float **' with an lvalue of type 'float **'
```

Why it even complies? I can pass something not const to a const.

I tried

```
reinterpret_cast<const float **>(inputChannelData)
```

but I get `Reinterpret_cast from 'float **' to 'const float **' casts away qualifiers`. What qualifiers? I'm actually putting a qualifier, not taking it out.

Comment: For adding (or removing) the `const` *qualifier* you need to use `const_cast`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but why the compiler even complains? It's not dangerous to pass a non const thing where a const thing is expected

Comment: It really depends on what is really `const`... There a real difference between `const float**` and `float* const *`. `float**` can be implicitly converted to `float* const*`, but not `const float**` (or `float const**` which might make it easier to understand)-

Comment: To rephrase it a little: Only the first level of indirection can be converted to `const`. So if you have `float*` then it can be converted to `float const*`. If you have `float**` then it can be converted to `float* const*`. If you have `float***` then it can be converted to `float** const*`. Etc.

Comment: What is the return type of `getArrayOfWritePointers`? Why can't you use it directly in the `processInput` call? Why do you need the (temporary?) variable `inputChannelData`?

Answer (score 3):

Since a `const float**` is a pointer to a **non-const** `const float*` (!), you can **write** a `const float*` to it:

```
const float f = 0.0f;
const float *p = &f; // Not itself const, points to one.
const float ** pp = &p
```

Obviously, a `float**` can't point to a `const float*`. If the cast were possible, you could sneak a `const float*` in a `float**`, and use that `float**` to then overwrite a `const float`